# ComboBox with databound SelectedItem is not updated at once

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview, combobox

On my form, I have a DataGridView with some DataGridViewComboBoxColumns, and some ComboBoxes. The DataGridView is bound to a BindingSource, and each of the ComboBoxes' SelectedItem property are bound to corresponding columns in the DataGridView. The pairs of  DataGridViewComboBoxColumns and ComboBoxes have the same DataSource for Items.

The expected behaviour is that when I change rows in the grid, the ComboBoxes should reflect the value of the corresponding column and newly selected row. What happens is that the ComboBoxes change according to the previously selected row (i.e. one step behind), causing the newly selected row's DataGridViewComboBoxColumns to be a clone of the last one's.

I have the same functionality working on other such pairs, the difference being that their DataSource is bound to a database, and the SelectedValue property is used instead.

Comment: What is your code behind changing the grid ?

Comment: By changing rows in the grid, I meant in the GUI when the user clicks in the grid or move up/down with the keyboard

Comment: Oke,and do you have any code behind that event or only property settings?

Comment: Nope, only the property settings. I've read about other people having problems with the SelectedItem property, which doesn't seem to behave as expected. Will try another approach by filling the ComboBoxes with objects instead of strings and use the SelectedValue property instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by using the SelectedValue property instead of SelectedItem. To be able to use this property, the ComboBox's .ValueMember has to be set, so I had to use objects with properties instead of simple strings in the list of ComboBox items. I created a class:

```
Public Class ComboItem
    Private cText As String
    Private cValue As Object
    Public Sub New(ByVal text As String, ByVal value As Object)
        Me.cText = text
        Me.cValue = value
    End Sub
    Public Sub New(ByVal text As String)
        Me.cText = text
        Me.cValue = text
    End Sub

    Public Property value() As Object
        Get
            Return cValue
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Object)
            cValue = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property text() As String
        Get
            Return cText
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            cText = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

And set up bindings like this:

```
Dim itemList As List(Of ComboItem) = New List(Of ComboItem) From {New ComboItem("", DBNull.Value),
                                                                  New ComboItem("Item 1"),
                                                                  New ComboItem("Item 2")}

Dim bindingSource As BindingSource = New BindingSource
bindingSource.DataSource = itemList
ComboBox1.DataSource = bindingSource
ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "text"
ComboBox1.ValueMember = "value"
dataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DataSource = bindingSource
dataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DisplayMember = "text"
dataGridViewTextBoxColumn.ValueMember = "value"
```

I set up the SelectedValue binding from the designer, but the code would look something like this:

```
ComboBox1.DataBindings.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.Binding("SelectedValue", dataGridViewBindingSource, "ColumnName", True))
```

This answer is really more like a workaround, because as far as I know, the SelectedItem method should work the same way (correct me if I'm wrong!).

Comment: gv.Columns[i].DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = "your value" gives a default value